# mysql join - how the flow works?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

using Mysql Server 5.5.

lets say I have two identical tables called foo1 and foo2 with the folowing columns:

surname varchar(20)
  idnum int(20)

and i want to join both tables where idnum=5

now if i implement it using the following code:

```
select * from foo1 
 join foo2 on foo1.idnum=foo2.idum
 where foo1.idnum5;
```

does it first joins all the rows in the tables and only then filters the where and returns the row with idnum5 ?

if it's true so i should probably implement it like that:

```
select * from foo1
 join foo2 on foo2.idnum=5
 where foo1.idnum=5
```

this implementation is a faster join ? is there any difference ?

I'm trying to understand how it actually works to know if this is one way to optimize my join queries.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The flow for the joins is just to PREPARE the relationships between the tables for final qualification.  The WHERE clause actually starts the application of which records to pull out as a PRIMARY and hopefully structured to take advantage of indexes to optimize the limited records from whatever tables are referenced in the WHERE portion.

From THAT result, the joins are applied (or left join/right join) and if so found in the corresponding allow THOSE records to be included, otherwise exclude from the primary set of data the WHERE clause allowed to go through.